# Understand MeshFunctions with Intercepts

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 7.0.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

While I've been thinking about [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59135/how-can-mathematica-help-me-to-find-a-real-radical-expression-for-roots-of-this) question, I tried to visualize the Intercepts. I use three snippets, actually snippet 1, 2 and 3. The visualization works as expected.

```
p[x_] := x^4 - 4 x^2 - 2 x + 1

solutions = NSolve[p[x] == 0, x]

snippet1 = 
  Plot[p[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
   MeshFunctions -> {p[x] /. x -> # &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
   PlotLabel -> "Snippet 1"];

snippet2 = 
  Show[Plot[p[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Brown], 
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, p[x]} /. solutions]}], 
   PlotLabel -> "Snippet 2"];

snippet3 = 
  Plot[p[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{x, 0} /. NSolve[p[x]]]}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Snippet 3"];
```

[image]

When applying snippet 1 with a larger xmin-value a fifth red spot appears. I do not observe this behavior on snippet 2 and 3. What's wrong with snippet 1, or with my knowledge/interpretation?

```
snippet1 = 
 Plot[p[x], {x, -3, 4}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
  MeshFunctions -> {p[x] /. x -> # &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
  PlotLabel -> "Snippet 1"]
```

[image]

I'm on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014).

Comment: This problem looks familiar, but perhaps it wasn't on this site that I've seen it.  At least I can't find it.  The problem goes back at least to V8.0.4 (Mac OS).  It doesn't happen if you use `PlotRange -> All`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Should this be tagged as a bug?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I think it ought to be considered a bug.  I've edited the question, hopefully in line with our current "bugs" style.

Comment: This still happens to 10.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very good question. You should not rely on `MeshFunctions`.

Follow the old path step for step:

```
fun = x^4 - 4 x^2 - 2 x + 1;

xvals = NSolve[fun == 0, x] // Values // Flatten
```

> {-1.48119, -1., 0.311108, 2.17009}

```
yvals = fun /. xvals // Chop
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0}

```
zeroes = Transpose[{xvals, yvals}]
```

> {{-1.48119, 0}, {-1., 0}, {0.311108, 0}, {2.17009, 0}}

```
snippet1 =
 Plot[fun, {x, -3, 5},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point /@ zeroes},
  PlotStyle -> Green,
  PlotLabel -> "Snippet 1"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

It looks like a bug. However there is a simple workaround: change the sign of your mesh function. In addition, `p[x] /. x -> # &` is equivalent to `#2 &`.

```
Plot[p[x], {x, -3, 4}, PlotStyle -> Green, MeshFunctions -> {-#2 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's a bug, and your "workaround" profits from this bug. +1 anyway :)